# Retrofit2 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, retrofit2

I've to create/register new User using retrofit2 my server side is

```
<?php

    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $gender= $_POST['gender'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "qwerty", "db");
    $query= mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(name,email, password, gender) VALUES('$name','$email', '$password', '$gender')");

    if($query){
        echo "You are sucessfully Registered";
    }

    else{
        echo "your details could not be registered";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

my model class is

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    public String email;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    public String password;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    public String gender;

    public User(String name, String email, String password, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
```

POST in service is

```
@POST("register.php")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```

posting data as

```
mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validateForm()){
                    mUserCall = mRestManager.getJobService()
                            .createUser(new User(mNameEditText.getText().toString(),
                                                mEmailEditText.getText().toString(),
                                                mPasswordEditText.getText().toString(),
                                                mGenders[position]));
                    mUserCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                            User user1 = response.body();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user1.name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

                            Log.e("REGISTER_ERROR", "Message is " + t.getMessage() );
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I've found some solutions and made change accordingly as

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("register.php")
    Call<User> createUser(@Field("name") String name,
                          @Field("email") String email,
                          @Field("password") String password,
                          @Field("gender") String gender);
```

but it also does not work, same error message, how to solve this error.

Comment: use call<ResponseBody>

Comment: add your json response

Comment: you are not returning a User object you are returning a String for Success/Failure in your PHP.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel how can I get User data from `call<ResponseBody>`?

Comment: I'm getting `okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@38c108b7` when I change `Call<ResponseBody>` and print `Log.e("RESPONSE", "Is " + response.body().toString());`

Comment: first run api from browser and then copy response and paste into  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. it generates pojo for you

Comment: OK my url is http://testapi-escot.rhcloud.com/register.php, how can I get response in this case when it only shows a message String? Sorry I'm not Php dev!

Comment: you get only sucess message right?

Comment: Yes and also the data is inserted in db!

Comment: but `onResponse()` is not executed at all.

Comment: it is beacuse you are using call<User>, but your api is sending only string.

Comment: `onFailure()` is called even data is inserted and the error message comes `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`

Comment: any change in Api or in my code please?

Comment: first ask api developer to send user details in JSON fromat, then you can use call<User>

Comment: Yep that sounds good I'll ask him!

Comment: OK thanks a lot Man!

Comment: here is sample json API developer need to send: {
  "name":"abc",
  "email":"gmail",
  "gender":"male"
 
}  then remove password from your pojo

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $` error even though I knew server was returning valid json.

After some hours debugging this I discovered it was due to me setting `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header to the request. This actually tells okhttp **not to** unzip the response and that the caller will do it himself. Due to this gson was trying to deserialize unzipped response and it's no wonder this was failing.

Answer (score 1):

Check your response, it is different than you are expecting.

Json must have start from "{" also response is different than your Pojo **User** so make new Pojo from new response.